# How to get url for specific store in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am developing a custom payment module and i need help in one thing!

when i click on place order on my onepagecheckout in magento url i am redirecting to my payment gateway which i am getting by this code

```
Mage::getUrl('comm/comm/redirect')
```

this generated the redirect url

My problem is when running multistore in magento for store www.abc.com this redirects works good and returns (www.abc.com/index.php/comm/comm/redirect)

But for another store www.def.com also it is redirecting to this same url (www.abc.com/index.php/comm/comm/redirect)

which it should be (www.def.com/index.php/comm/comm/redirect) so that this store redirects to its own specific payment gateway.

How could i get the specific store url when clicking on place order.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

`Mage::getUrl()` can take two parameters:

Parameter 1 - **$routePath** -> The route path expressed in the form of  "module/controller/action"

Parameter 2 - **$routeParams** -> This is an array that converts key/values into pairs of path directories.

Magento will use the correct domain as the base URL if you add the `_store` param. e.g.

```
Mage::getUrl('comm/comm/redirect', array(
    '_store'=>'your_store_id'
));
```

OR

```
Mage::getUrl('comm/comm/redirect', array(
    '_store'=>'your_store_code'
));
```

For additional reference and a complete list of options available visit: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function similar to this in your block:

```
function getStoreByCode($storeCode)
{
    $stores = array_keys(Mage::app()->getStores());
    foreach($stores as $id){
      $store = Mage::app()->getStore($id);
      if($store->getCode()==$storeCode) {
        return $store;
      }
     }
     return Mage::app()->getStore(); // if not found
}
```

Then in your template file call the function and pass the store code into it:

```
$store = $this->getStoreByCode(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());
echo $store->getUrl('comm/comm/redirect');
```

I tested it and it works fine.